# Simple PHP Email form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Very simple email form code. Worked once, but won't work anymore, even at different addresses. That is to say the emails no longer show up, but I'm not erroring out eather.

```
<form action="/mail-us.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

And here is the PHP

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "blah@x-matic.net";
    $subject = "X-Matic Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error sending email!");
?>
```

Note, I tested the email out with my gmail account (from gmail to email, instead of from form to email) and it worked.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". mail() returns false? Your SMTP server rejects it? Did you check spam folders on either side?

Comment: When an email script "doesn't work" the problem could be anywhere along the chain of events between the code and the inbox, most of which have nothing to do with the code.  Can you point it to an SMTP server that you can watch/control and see if it receives the email?  If it does, the code is working.

Answer (score 0):

Use SMTP mail when in localhost, and switch to mail() once the site is in a webserver (i.e your webhost)

At least that is what i do.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to install [Pegasus Mail](http://pmail.com) on your computer, the `mail()` function will not work on your localhost computer, as your computer does not have a mail server installed.

Either that, or use SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $to = "xxx@google.com";
    $subject = "Email from Sender; // quotation marks end ;
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
else
{
    echo "Mail sending Failure!";
}
?>
```

try this